# Regular Expression to Split this string

Tags: php, regex

I want to split following string with a comma.

```
1,"x1",43,"tr","y,7"
```

Result array should be like following.

```
0=>1
1=>"x1"
2=>43
3=>"tr"
4=>"y,7"
```

In short, it should not consider comma if it is between quotes.

If I use explode, I will get following result, which I don't want.

```
[4:58:20 PM] Mihir Dhandha: 0=>1
1=>"x1"
2=>43
3=>"tr"
4=>"y
5=>7"
```

I am stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy!! Your string is a CSV.

Use `$your_array=str_getcsv($your_string);`

Comment: You made my day... I am a .net coder so I was struggling with this small php problem. You made it easy like nothing :)

Comment: I don't understand why anyone has checked my answer like "unaccept". I think that it's OK.
Ok, the problem is my bad english???  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
<?php

$s = '1,"x1",43,"tr","y,7"';
$result = str_getcsv($s);
var_dump($result);
echo "\n";

// array(5) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(1) "1"
//   [1]=>
//   string(2) "x1"
//   [2]=>
//   string(2) "43"
//   [3]=>
//   string(2) "tr"
//   [4]=>
//   string(3) "y,7"
// }


?>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Note: it only works with 5.3 and above, but the comments have a workaround for older versions.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet:

```
$s = '1,"x1",43,"tr","y,7"';
print_r(preg_split('/,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', $s));
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => "x1"
    [2] => 43
    [3] => "tr"
    [4] => "y,7"
)
```

as can be seen on [ideone](http://ideone.com/rHTcU).

The regex `,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` means: match a comma, only if it has zero, or an even number of double quotes ahead of it.

Comment: Assuming that the string is being read left to right, should this check for an even number of double quotes behind rather than ahead?

Comment: @Rob Young, it doesn't matter if you look ahead or behind. Note that many regex implementations do not support look behinds that have no obvious length, so look ahead is the "safe" way, in this case. (or even safer, use a built-in CSV function as others suggested)